# Is "git config --global mergetool.bc3 trustExitCode true" a correct usage of git-config?

Tags: git, beyondcompare4

[Using Beyond Compare with Version Control Systems under OS X](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs_osx) uses:

```
git config --global mergetool.bc3 trustExitCode true
```

But [Using Beyond Compare with Version Control Systems](http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs) uses:

```
 git config --global mergetool.bc3.trustExitCode true
```

I think that the first usage of `git config` is incorrect since I can't find a description about it in [git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config). Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reading the Git doc, I think your understanding is correct.

In the [Git configuration chapter of the official](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) doc, there is a section named **External Merge and Diff Tools**.

In it, you can find the following lines of configuration:

```
git config --global merge.tool extMerge
git config --global mergetool.extMerge.trustExitCode false
```

`extMerge` refers to a wrapper script but the syntax is the same for any supported tools (gvimdiff, kdiff3, meld, vimdiff, and tortoisemerge).